# How to move files to a sub-directory based on a text file

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, mv

I have a directory with around 2000 files in it.

```
~/
-File 1.pdf
-File2.pdf
-Another file 1.pdf
-File3.pdf
-Someother file.docx
-Yeanother.pdf
```

I have mapped each file with the account it relates to. This mapping is in a CSV file.

**File Name** & **Destination**

```
File 1.pdf          | CompanyAccount1
File2.pdf           | CompanyAccount1
Another file 1.pdf  | CompanyAcountA
File3.pdf           | CompanyAccount5
Someother file.docx | AnotherAccount2
Yeanother.pdf       | CompanyAccount1
```

I would like to move the files from the main directory into sub-directories based on the account name based on the csv (or text file).

**Desired Result**

```
~/
-CompanyAccount1
--File 1.pdf
--File2.pdf
--Yeanother.pdf
-CompanyAcountA
--Another file 1.pdf
-CompanyAccount5
--File3.pdf 
-AnotherAccount2
--Someother file.docx
```

Ideally it would be something as simple as `mv < file-and-destination.csv`, but I can't get it to work. I've tried `xargs mv < renaming.txt`, but it doesn't work as expected (some were moved and then everything else was moved into a single directory).

Comment: Please share what you tried...

Comment: and some working example...also when you say that the files "relates to" an account, do you mean "owned by" ?

Comment: Loop on the CSV, read the values (account and filename), create directory "account" if it does not exist, move "filename" into that directory, keep looping.  No attempt, no free code :-)

Comment: I've done a lot of variations on this, xargs -I {} mv {} < renaming.txt, an Apple Script, a bash script. I can put the things I've tried, but they are variations of things i've pulled off of stack overflow and other forums, so I don't see the value. Most sites deal with moving files in a list into one directory, but I have not seen both the source and destination from a text file, so I thought it useful to ask here in case others run into it.

Answer (score 0):

Create the directories:

```
cut -f2 file-and-destination.csv |
xargs mkdir -p
```

This assumes the text is tab-delimited, and that no filenames contain a tab.

If none of the file names contained whitespace, you could simply `xargs -n 2 mv <file-and-destination.csv` but the way it is now (assuming your sample is representative), a simple `while IFS=$'\t' read -r file dir` loop seems like the way to go.

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r file dir; do
    mv "$file" "$dir"
done <file-and-destination.csv
```

Another solution is to generate a script to generate the directories and move the files. This one assumes there are no file names with single quotes in them, either;

```
sed $'s/\\([^\t]*\\)\t\\(.*\\)/mkdir -p \'\\2\'; mv \'\\1\' \'\\2\''
```

This just generates the commands; pipe to `sh` if the result looks reasonable.

I use Bash "C-style strings `$'...'` throughout as a convenience. If you don't have Bash, the second one in particular will require some refactoring. In the first, you should be able to simply drop the dollar sign and type a literal tab between the single quotes (in many shells, <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> to get a literal tab character on the command line).

All in all, I would not recommend the latter technique. If you have control over the input file format, simply putting `destdir/file` to say that `file` should be moved to `destdir` might be a better design (because splitting on a slash is easy and natural, and now you can have file names with tabs, too).

Comment: The first solution works. I added a mkdir command into the loop, but your solution is better to avoid getting a bunch of errors for when multiple files go into a single directory. I've also changed the tab to a pipe as it made it much easier.